# How tochange color of a textView in onclick listener in a list fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I was trying to change the color of a text view in a list fragment after  onclick button.
Im using an add button(addBtn) to add the contents to list dynamically an another button(clrBtn) to change the color of the textview which is already added to the list
Im getting a nullPointerException. Can you please let me know where am i going wrong

Below is my code :

```
public class FragmentOne extends ListFragment {
String[] order = new String[] {};
int[] qty;

public FragmentOne(){}

/** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
SimpleAdapter adapter1;
// Keys used in Hashmap
String[] from = { "num","itm","price","qty" };

// Ids of views in listview_layout
int[] to = { R.id.num,R.id.itm,R.id.price,R.id.qty};


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    Button addBtn,clrBtn;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    addBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    clrBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

    addBtn.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //ListFragment fragment=new FragmentProdQtyPrice();
            Fragment fragment=new FragmentExListView();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("fragmentId", 1);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    });

    clrBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            /*MainActivity.aList.clear();
            adapter1=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), MainActivity.aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);
            setListAdapter(adapter1);*/
            LinearLayout tv=(LinearLayout)arg0.findViewById(R.id.listtest);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

        }
    });

    adapter1=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), MainActivity.aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter1); 
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String prompt = 
            "clicked item: " + getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),prompt , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}}
```

Edited:

My Layout files :

Fragment_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="add" />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Clr" />
</LinearLayout>
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/LinearLayout02" />
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/LinearLayout02"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/txtEmpty" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

listview_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listtest"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/num"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" android:textSize="15sp" /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where you are getting an error. Means on which line you are getting an error.

Comment: do you want xml solution?

Comment: Looks like you try to find a view inside the button, in the `clrBtn.setOnClickListener`. A button is not able to contain an other view in its self (since it extends `View`, not `ViewGroup`). Where is the actual TestView that you'd like to change the background color?

Comment: @AmolTate m getting nul pointer exception inside the  clrBtn.setOnClickListener

Comment: Could you share your fragment_1.xml code?

Comment: @LJoosse i would like to change the color of atextView(num) in listview_layout.xml.

Comment: R you sure you are getting error on clrBtn.setOnClickListener on this line?

Comment: Now I got your problem your fetching view from button. Button doesnt have any child view\

Comment: Please refer my answer

Comment: no not yet.. :( still searching :'(

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution:
You are looking child view in Button element. Button element doesn't have any child element.

```
clrBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(FragmentOne.this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout,null);
            LinearLayout tv=(LinearLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.listtest);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm getting an error : The method inflate(int, ViewGroup) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: I did not get any error but the color was not updated